# How can I use a command line vpn in CRONTAB?

Tags: bash, vpn, cron, openvpn

I'm trying to use the nordvpn/windscribe/expressvpn command line utility (take your pick, ive tried them all) to schedule a change to my IP address every 5 minutes.

Using these in the interactive bash work fine:

```
nordvpn connect
windscribe connect best
expressvpn connect usla
```

However in crontab none work (I'm omitting the disconnects for brevity):

`sudo crontab -e`

```
*/5 * * * * nordvpn connect
*/5 * * * * windscribe connect best
*/5 * * * * expressvpn connect usla
```

Is there a way to schedule a connection to a VPN? Thanks.

Comment: Two things, first, if you don't use `sudo` in bash then you should not use `sudo` before `crontab -e` to do the same thing. Second, crontab does not know about path. Whatever command you use in crontab, you need to provide the full path, for example `*/5 * * * *  /use/bin/nordvpn connect`

Comment: Why would you do this like this? Put the lines in a script and execute the script. These commands like this are NOT executed after another but at the same time where it is unknown which of the 3 is quickest. But you do want the 1st to finish 1st. So this is not going to work.